# I want to hook controller_action_postdispatch whenever reload the page i get all the detail of that page

Tags: magento2.3

I'm new in Magento2 and I want to know the detail of controller_action_postdispatch events like controller Name, action name,module name and all the details related to that event. I have created an events.xml file where I called the event name then try to get the details from the observer. My question is how to get the details on that event? 
I have found $this->_request->getControllerModule(); but I couldn't use \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request in observer.

Is there any

**Here is my events.xml code**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="controller_action_postdispatch">
        <observer name="category" instance="Comlitix\ComlitixInfo\Observer\Category"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

**Here is observer file**

```
<?php

namespace Comlitix\ComlitixInfo\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Manager;

class Category implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        echo'Hello world';
        die;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the below are all variables that do exist in your event:

```
$event = $observer->getEvent();
$controller = $observer->getControllerAction();
$request = $observer->getRequest();
```

Answer (score 0):

your event.xml  is containing only *controller_action_postdispatch* which is not correct:

Below are controller action events:

Controllers:
controller_action_predispatch_ [ROUTE_NAME]
controller_action_predispatch_ [FULL_ACTION_NAME]
controller_action_postdispatch_ [ROUTE_NAME]
controller_action_postdispatch_ [FULL_ACTION_NAME]
controller_action_layout_render_before_ [FULL_ACTION_NAME]